# What is the most efficient way to update record(s) value when using SummingCombiner?

Tags: accumulo

I have a table with a SummingCombiner on minC and majC.  Every day I need to update the value for a small number of records.  What is the most efficient way to do so?

My current implementation is to create a new record with value set to amount to increase/decrease (new mutation w/Row,CF,CQ equal to existing record(s)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the most efficient way to update the value is to insert a new record and let the SummingCombiner add the new value into the existing value. You probably also want to have the SummingCombiner configured on the scan scope, so that scans will see the updated value right away, before a major compaction has occurred.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I read somewhere online that configuring the SummingCombiner on the scan scope could impact query performance.  You suggest I configure on all three(scan, minC, and maxC)?

Comment: Yes. If you only have a few records for each key, I wouldn't expect there to be a significant impact on query performance. Also, the query results will not be correct unless you configure the combiner on scan.